# Rotate view/object based on how far and fast I slide my finger across the screen (Android

Tags: android, swipe, pull-to-refresh

Similar to pull-to-refresh functionality I want to rotate a view (maybe a small image)
based on how far a slide my finger across the screen (anywhere on the screen)....once my finger leaves the screen I want the view to rotate in reverse back to its original state

To give some more information about my intended use of this functionality:
I have an image and when the user swipes their finger across this image (right) for a certain distance and then releases the swipe I want to open a new activity 
The rotating object just provides some visual feedback for the users swipe gesture

I tried to implement this using Rotation Animation and had a very difficult time, I also cant find any answers any were on the web...if someone could help me it would be a life saver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onTouchEvent` method of `Activity` to listen for user gestures. Then in `onTouchEvent` use `GestureDetector` to be notified about gestures. You can use `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` to be notified about `onScroll` event. Then rotate your view using `ObjectAnimator` class. This Android tutorial shows how to discover and utilize Scroll gesture. [Animating a Scroll Gesture](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html)

Comment: the difficulty I had wasn't necessarily in detecting the gesture but more so in animating the view in proportion to the length of the gesture

Comment: I created an animation that rotated the view when the user slide their finger across the screen and when the user's fingers leaves the screen the animation stopped and  a new reverse rotation animation started...the difficulty I had was in getting the Rotation animation to stop at whatever angular position it was at and start a reverse animation

Comment: I understand that you used View Animation system for rotation animation. It for sure would be easier if you use Property Animation system. It's available since API 11 but if you would like to support earlier versions there's NineOldAndroid library. [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com)

Comment: @user3711987 could you post your working code as an answer that would help